# Turn Router Into Advanced Repeater

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

My PC is really great, but it doesn't have a wireless reciever, and they're although cheap these days, hard to ship to where I live.

I have an old RNX-N150RT Router, and was wondering if I could somehow configure it to do the following:

- Connect to my home router
- Take the packets/signal from the router
- Send it through an ethernet port to my computer

I basically want to configure the router to be a repeater that can repeat a wifi network through an ethernet cable. I have tried OpenWRT, but I'm not too network savvy, so I don't really understand what I should be doing. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: [Here](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/clientmode#bridged_client_mode_issues)’s why this won’t work without some tricks like WDS. Do you have OpenWrt on both devices? What make and model is the “current” WiFi router?

Comment: current router was supplied by optimum, running their own firmware, and can't really change that. Don't know make or model @DanielB

Comment: Oh okay, so that’s pretty bad. Do you have other devices on the network you wish to communicate with? Do you have port forwards set up to your PC?

Comment: No port forwards setup, just looking to connect my PC to the outside world @DanielB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, since you want to connect only a single PC to a network with nothing else (or nothing else to talk to), you could go with a “routed client” setup. It’s very simple, OpenWrt supports it out of the box. It comes in two flavors: with or without NAT. The latter is better, but you have to be able to set up routes on your main router.

### [With NAT](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/routedclient#usingmasquerade):

#### `/etc/config/network`

Remove `ifname`s from `wan` interface, it should look like this:

```
config 'interface' 'wan'
        option 'proto'      'dhcp'
```

(yes, that’s one option only)

#### `/etc/config/wireless`

Remove any `disabled` entries or make the value `0`.

Add information about your wireless network:

```
config 'wifi-iface'
        option 'device'     'wlan0'
        option 'network'    'wan'
        option 'mode'       'sta'
        option 'ssid'       'Vodafone-0E0301'
        option 'encryption' 'psk2'
        option 'key'        'secret-key'
```

Remove other `wifi-iface` sections.

You also need to set the proper channel or you can try setting it to `auto`.

#### Before proceeding

If your current network is in the 192.168.**1**.0-255 IP range, you need to make OpenWrt use something else, in `/etc/config/network`:

```
config interface 'lan'
...
        option proto 'static'
        option ipaddr '192.168.2.1'
...
```

Afterwards just reboot the router. Remember to refresh your DHCP address if you changed the IP range!

### [Fully routed](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/routedclient#usingrouting):

Do all of the above.

#### `/etc/config/firewall`

Disable NAT for the WAN zone, allow traffic in:

```
config 'zone'
        option 'name'       'wan'
...
        option 'input'      'ACCEPT'
...
        option 'masq'       '0'
```

Add a new forwarding section somewhere in the file, maybe next to the others:

```
config 'forwarding'
        option 'src'        'wan'
        option 'dest'       'lan'
```

#### Before proceeding

Your main router needs a route. Routes need static IP addresses. If you can, set a DHCP reservation on your main router so the client router always gets the same IP address.

If you cannot, change the `wan` configuration in `/etc/config/network`:

```
config interface 'wan'
        option proto 'static'
        option ipaddr '192.168.178.254'
        option netmask '255.255.255.0'
        option gateway '192.168.178.1'
        list dns '8.8.8.8'
        list dns '8.8.4.4'
```

Add a static route on your main router. If you used 192.168.**2**.1 on your client router and its WAN address is 192.168.178.254, add the following route:

Destination: 192.168.2.0
Netmask: 255.255.255.0 (or /24)
Gateway: 192.168.178.254

After rebooting your client router, everything should still work but you won’t have double NAT.

If you use the LUCI web interface, you may be able to accomplish tasks like selecting the wireless network more easily. I wouldn’t recommend it though, because almost all official documentation is based on the config files.

<sub>*Most of the snippets above were taken/adapted from the linked OpenWrt guides.*</sub>